# Perl Dynamically Generated Multidimentional Associative Array

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, associative-array

This may be a simple oversight on my part (or something much more advanced than my skill set).  I am trying to dynamically fill a 2d associative array by reading input from a file.

```
my @data;
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;

    my $ID,$COUNT;
    print "READ: " . $_ . "\n"; #Debug 1

    ($ID,$COUNT,undef,undef,undef) = split /\,/;
    print "DATA: " . $ID . "," . $COUNT . "\n"; # Debug 2

    $data{$ID}{"count"} = $COUNT;
    #push @{$data{$ID}{"count"}}, $COUNT; 

              print $data{$ID}{"count"} . "\n"; # Debug 3
}
```

The first print (Debug 1) will print a line similar to des313,3,,,.

The second print (Debug 2) will print a line DATA: des313,3

The third print (Debug 3) will print a blank line.

The issue seems to be in the way I am trying to insert the data into the associative array.  I have tried both the direct insert and the push method with no results.  I have done this with PHP however I think I am overlooking this in Perl.  I did look at the perldoc perldsc page in the section of HASHES of HASHES however I did not see it talk about dynamic generation of them.  Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Although it could be improved your code works fine for me as it stands. The third debug line correctly prints the stored value of $COUNT. Please check this code again and tell us what results you get and the contents of the data file you are using.

Comment: If you're learning Perl from a source that uses the term "associative array" then it is almost certainly horribly out of date. Please look for something that isn't over 15 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning to the hash the way you have should work fine.  You are declaring your variables improperly.  Your associative array is called a hash in Perl, and is prefixed with a `%` sigil, so you should write `my %data` before the while loop.  Inside the loop, the `my` operator needs parens to apply to a list, so it should be `my ($ID, $COUNT);`.

This minimal example works properly:

```
use warnings;  # place these lines at the top of all of your programs
use strict;    # they will catch many errors for you

my %data;  # hash variable
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($id, $count) = split /,/;  # simplify the split

    $data{$id}{count} = $count;    # build your hash
}

print "got: $data{des313}{count}\n";  # prints "got: 3"

__DATA__
des313,3
```

Comment: Taking your solution it works just fine.  However if I make the changes in my code it does not even after fixing some issues.

Comment: After doing some troubleshooting figured out what was happening.  My print statement had print $data{$ID}{count} . " \n" (extra space before \n).  I removed the extra space and I got the results I wanted.  Not sure exactly how the extra space would result in no output however it works now.  Thanks!